# Hyphen/dash attributes instead of underscore in Haml

Tags: haml

Doing this

```
li{ id: ["article", article.id] }
```

results in

```
# => <li id="article_1"></li>
```

I want to have it output this instead, while using similar dynamic syntax, rather than string parsing.

```
# => <li id="article-1"></li>
```

without doing

```
%li{ id: "entry-#{entry.id}" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you cannot do this. I hope haml realizes people don't do underscores for element names, and that the naysayers who object to implementing something like this on the grounds of complexity realize they're just arguing from status quo.

In the meanwhile, you can just do this, which is slightly more manual.

`li{ id: "article-#(article.id)" }`